# Wordpress translation loading english file

Tags: translation, localization, plugin-qtranslate

I am trying to translate a wordpress site but whatever I do the english file is always loaded.

In functions.php I've set `load_theme_textdomain('twentyeleven', get_template_directory() . '/languages');`

In the template page I use `<?php _e('HOME', 'twentyeleven'); ?>`

And in `wp-config.php` the language is set like this (I use the qtranslate plugin)

```
$enabledLanguages = qtrans_getSortedLanguages();
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = explode('/', $uri);

if (in_array($path[1], $enabledLanguages)) {
    define('_1D1F_LANG_', $path[1]);

    if (_1D1F_LANG_ == 'en') {
        define('WPLANG', 'en_US'); // exception to set en_US not en_EN ;_;
    }
    else {
        $lang = _1D1F_LANG_.'_'.strtoupper(_1D1F_LANG_);
        define('WPLANG', $lang);
    }
}
else {
    $defaultLang = get_option('qtranslate_default_language');
    define('_1D1F_LANG_', $defaultLang);
    define('WPLANG', 'en_US');
}
```

The `WPLANG` constant is correctly set, but the en_US.mo file is always loaded not matter what happens.

Anybody has an idea what I am doing wrong? I've used the same process on another site and it worked...

Comment: are you building a child theme of twentyeleven?

Comment: Have you tried doing a var_dump() on the $path array? English is the fallback in many situations (two of them in your own function), so there are many ways this could be going wrong. More debug information would be great.

Comment: @Ahmad M Not a child theme, but I've used twentyeleven as a basis to build my theme

Comment: @tbuteler There is no problem with `$path`, and even if I manually define `WPLANG` to `fr_FR` for example, it still does not work.

Comment: Look here - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92560/translate-wordpress-plugin and read the necessary instructions. You need to define the language files and function names correctly. Also, `define('WPLANG', '');` sometimes means english language too, without en_US.