# Translate wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, translation

Below is a small tutorial of translation from English To German. (You can change the it as your needs).

in any plugin file, it has unique name in its header.

```
/*
Plugin Name: SampleTut
.......
*/
```

in that plugin folder, make a folder (named "languages");

into your plugin .php file (somewhere in top), insert this initialisation code:

```
class load_my_language 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    add_action('init', array($this, 'load_translat'));
    }

     public function load_translal()
    {
        load_plugin_textdomain('SampleTut', FALSE, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'/languages/');
    }
}

$ggg = new load_my_language ;
```

then open new text file and insert this code: (Now, we only make two messages, "helo" and "bye". You can insert as much as you need).

```
# English translations for PACKAGE package.
# Copyright (C) 2012 THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# Automatically generated, 2012.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: SampleTut 1.1\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2012-11-11 21:33-0400\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2013-11-21 12:33+0400\n"
"Last-Translator: Automatically generated\n"
"Language-Team: none\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: iso-8859-1\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.5.4\n"


#: myplugininfile.php:47 (this is a note line)
msgid "mymessage1"
msgstr "Hello"

#: myplugininfile.php:48
msgid "mymessage2"
msgstr "Bye"
```

save this file and name it "SampleTut-en_US.po" (note, that .po should be an extension of the file, and not .po.txt)

download the software: POEDIT, and open that file and Press CTRL+S and thus, the program automatically generates the second functional .mo file ( If it doesnt generate the .mo file automatically, then edit preferences.);
Then shutdown the program, and reopen the file again.
Make your translations in "translation" fields, and after you finish, click SAVE AS and save the file as "SampleTut-de_DE"
Now, the two German files will be generated.

then put those two English and two German files into "languages" folder.

Then, open wp-config.php and from default(English):

```
define ('WPLANG, '');
```

change to

```
define ('WPLANG, 'de_DE');
```

(This means, that we changed our wordpress main language. then worpdress will read our language file, with prefix -de_DE)

so, now open your plugin's .php file, and where you have any echo-ed word:

```
echo "Something";
```

change to :

```
echo __("mymessage1", 'SampleTut');
```

or the same as echo:

```
__e("mymessage1", 'SampleTut');
```

And thus, the wordpress shows you the appropriate translation for that id (mymessage1).

references:
    codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers
    codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress
    codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin
    codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language

Comment: Is this a question? If not, you should make a question out of it and post your tutorial as answer and mark it as solution two days later. Please also get in touch with the WYSIWYG editor, which will help you format this properly.

Comment: Nice contribution, but take a look at the pages [About] and [FAQ] to format this in a Question & Answer fashion.

Comment: instead of `echo __($string)` try its shorthand `_e($string)`. More of these: http://codex.wordpress.org/L10n

Answer (score 2):

Do not create a PO file manually. The synchronization must be automatic, or you will waste much time. Each you change a string, you have to change it in two files now.

[Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) has a built-in PHP parser. Use it to read your project files.

[image]

And you don't have to edit `WPLANG` to create a translation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/) plugin.

It's even easier to use than Poedit and you don't have to install any programs on your computer. You can translate everything directly in your wp-admin.

It will scan your plugin files and find all strings to translate. Then you can translate them to any language you like.